# How to ask highest temperature for a gadget ? - word choice issue

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I don't know how to word this in proper English ..

So I want to ask a question,

"What is the highest temperature this gadget can take ? "

I think people will understand what I am saying, but I want to know if there is a better way to word this ?

Thanks,

Comment: There are often two ***different*** maximum temperature values for a gadget - "operating" and "storage". When it's turned on it might *temporarily not function correctly* above a certain temperature, but the other limit usually implies the device may be *permanently damaged* if it's exceeded. Of course, for many heat-generating devices, they're not likely to approach the second limit *unless* they're turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is similar to the [*operating temperature*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_temperature).

In your sentence, there are a couple of words which might work:

- [Withstand](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/withstand)
- [Endure](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endure)
- [Survive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/survive)

> What is the highest temperature this gadget can withstand?

Unless it is something like a thermometer, then

> What is the highest temperature this gadget can measure?

makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking for the

> **maximum** operating temperature

above which temperature *something* will stop working (either graceful degradation or cataclysmic fault).

Do you want to know the maximum temperature for operation or for component failure, e.g. components start to melt because of ambient temperature stress?